# Can Ansible unarchive be made to write static folder modification times?

Tags: wordpress, ansible

I am writing a build process for a WordPress installation using Ansible. It doesn't have a application-level build system at the moment, and I've chosen Ansible so that it can cleanly integrate with server build scripts, so I can bring up a working server at the touch of a button.

Most of my WordPress plugins are being installed with the `unarchive` feature, pointing to versioned plugin builds on the official wordpress.org installation server. I've encountered a problem with just one of these, which is that it is always being marked as "changed" even though the files are exactly the same.

Having examined the state of `ls -Rl` before and after, I noticed that this plugin (WordPress HTTPS) is the only one to use internal sub-directories, and upon each decompression, the modification time of folders is getting bumped.

It may be useful to know that this is a project build script, with a `connection` of `local`. I guess therefore that means that SSH is not being used.

Here is a snippet of my playbook:

```
- name: Install the W3 Total Cache plugin
  unarchive: >
    src=https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/w3-total-cache.0.9.4.1.zip
    dest=wp-content/plugins
    copy=no

- name: Install the WP DB Manager plugin
  unarchive: >
    src=https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-dbmanager.2.78.1.zip
    dest=wp-content/plugins
    copy=no

# @todo Since this has internal sub-folders, need to work out
# how to preserve timestamps of the original folders rather than
# re-writing them, which forces Ansible to record a change of
# server state.
- name: Install the WordPress HTTPS plugin
  unarchive: >
    src=https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wordpress-https.3.3.6.zip
    dest=wp-content/plugins
    copy=no
```

One hacky way of fixing this is to use `ls -R` before and after, using options to include file sizes but not timestamps, and then `md5sum` that output. I could then mark it as changed if there is a change in checksum. It'd work but it's not very elegant (and I'd want to do that for all plugins, for consistency).

Another approach is to abandon the task if a plugin file already exists, but that would cause problems when I bump the plugin version number to the latest copy.

Thus, ideally, I am looking for a switch to present to `unarchive` to say that I want the folder modification times from the zip file, not from playbook runtime. Is it possible?

---

Update: a commenter asked if the file contents could have changed in any way. To determine whether they have, I wrote this script, which creates a checksum for (1) all file contents and (2) all file/directory timestamps:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Save pwd and then change dir to root location
STARTDIR=`pwd`
cd `dirname $0`/../..

# Clear collation file
echo > /tmp/wp-checksum

# List all files recursively
find wp-content/plugins/wordpress-https/ -type f | while read file
do
    #echo $file
    cat $file >> /tmp/wp-checksum
done

# Get checksum of file contents
sha1sum /tmp/wp-checksum

# Get checksum of file sizes
ls -Rl wp-content/plugins/wordpress-https/ | sha1sum

# Go back to original dir
cd $STARTDIR
```

I ran this as part of my playbook (running it in isolation using tags) and received this:

```
PLAY [Set this playbook to run locally] ****************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [jonblog : Run checksum command] ******************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [jonblog : debug] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "checksum_before.stdout_lines": [
        "374fadc4df1578f78fd60b1be6758477c2c533fa  /tmp/wp-checksum", 
        "10d66f7bdbbdd3af531d1b11a3db3059a5868838  -"
    ]
}

TASK [jonblog : Install the WordPress HTTPS plugin] ***************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [jonblog : Run checksum command] ******************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [jonblog : debug] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "checksum_after.stdout_lines": [
        "374fadc4df1578f78fd60b1be6758477c2c533fa  /tmp/wp-checksum", 
        "719c9da94b525e723b1abe188ee9f5bbaf121f3f  -"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=6    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

The debug lines reflect the checksum hash of the contents of the files (this is identical) and then the checksum hash of `ls -Rl` of the file structure (this has changed). This is in keeping with my prior manual finding that directory checksums are changing.

So, what can I do next to track down why folder modification times are incorrectly flagging this operation as changed?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the contents are the same each time? What happens if you md5sum everything and then run your play and check again? I'd be very surprised if Ansible is overwriting a file with the same contents but there may be a bug somewhere. The first thing that comes to mind is that the WP installation is modifying one of those files after it being copied.

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR. I am fairly sure, yes - though I hadn't thought to tag this command and run it solo, so I will do that next. I believe the contents of the archive are completely identical on every run, but it is possible that there is something else monkeying with the directory. It won't be WP though - I am not running any WP PHP installation code as part of this playbook.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR: I have done the research you've suggested, and found that the files are indeed byte identical - just the folder timestamps are changing. Any new ideas? I will use my checksum script in the meantime as a measure of change, which will get me idempotent for now - but it would be nice to do this properly (or to report a bug to the core Ansible team).

Comment: Not getting much in the way of bites on my bounty... is it worth filing as a bug? I've fixed the problem using my checksum script, so the problem is averted for me and it can stay like that - but it would be nice to fix it for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to modify the checksum script and to make that a permanent feature of the Ansible process. It feels a bit hacky to do my own checksumming, when Ansible should do it for me, but it works.

New answers that explain that I am doing something wrong, or that a new version of Ansible fixes the problem, would be most welcome.

If I get a moment, I will raise this as a possible bug with the Ansible team. However I do sometimes wonder about the effort/reward ratio when raising bugs on a busy tracker - I already have one item outstanding, it has been waiting a while, and I've chosen to work around that too.

### Update (18 months later)

This Ansible build system never made it into live. It felt like I was always working around something. Recently, when I decided I needed to move my blog to another server, I finally Dockerised it. This took several weeks (since there is a surprising amount of things to think about in a real WordPress installation) but in general I found the process much nicer than using orchestration tools.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than overwriting all files each time and find a way to keep the same modification datetime, you may want to use the `creates` option of the `unarchive` module.

As you maybe already know, this tells Ansible that a specific file/folder will be created as a result of the task. Thus, next time the task will **not** be run again if that file/folder already exists.

See http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/unarchive_module.html#options

Comment: Yes, I thought about that - sorry I didn't make my penultimate paragraph a bit clearer, but that's what I was referring to. The problem with this approach, as I see it, is when I bump `wordpress-https.3.3.6.zip` to `wordpress-https.3.3.7.zip` due to a new release, the task will claim to have succeeded on an existing installation when in reality it has done nothing.

Comment: However another way I could do it is to use a temp folder to assemble the app, and to delete everything in the `plugins` folder. All of these tasks could be marked as `changed_when: False`, and then I `synchronize` them into place, which produces a changed/unchanged output.

Comment: Ah, no that won't work either - changing folder timestamps again! Bah... So, thank you for the above suggestion but do you have any further ideas? `:-)`